# Neo4j Cypher find entity by exact collection of associated nodes(ids)

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In my Neo4j/SDN4 project I have a following node entity:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Nomination extends Commentable {

    private final static String CONTAINS = "CONTAINS";
    private final static String DEFINED_BY = "DEFINED_BY";

    private String name;

    @Relationship(type = CONTAINS, direction = Relationship.OUTGOING)
    private Set<Criterion> criteria = new HashSet<>();

...

}
```

I need to implement a Cypher query that will try to find `Nomination` by exact collection of associated criteria (by criterion ids).

Right now I have a following query:

```
MATCH (n:Nomination)-[:CONTAINS]->(c:Criterion) WHERE id(n) = {nominationId} AND id(c) IN {criterionIds} RETURN n
```

but it is not enough because of `Nomination` can contain less criteria that was provided in `{criterionIds}` but I need to check exact match(order of criteria doesn't matter)

How to reimplement this query in order to do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use COLLECT and then ALL function.

https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/predicates/#functions-all

```
MATCH (n:Nomination)-[:CONTAINS]->(c:Criterion) 
WHERE id(n) = {nominationId}
WITH n,COLLECT(id(c)) AS foundCritIds
WHERE ALL (id IN {criterionIds} WHERE id in foundCritIds) 
RETURN n
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate approach, you may want to PROFILE each to see which works best for you:

```
MATCH (c:Criterion)
WHERE id(c) in {criterionIds}
WITH COLLECT(c) as criterion
WITH criterion, head(criterion) as firstC
MATCH (firstC)<-[:CONTAINS]-(n:Nomination)
WHERE SIZE((n)-[:CONTAINS]->(:Criterion)) = SIZE(criterion)
 AND ALL(crit in criterion[1..] WHERE (n)-[:CONTAINS]->(crit))    
RETURN n
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution !